# UIPageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController never called

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I have a UIPageViewController that I've set up with an array as the datasource. I see the first page fine and the presentation count dots show up correctly, but when I try to drag the to the next page nothing happens. So I set up some breakpoints in the `viewControllerAfterViewController` as well as `Before` methods and **they never get called on**. The other dataSource methods for `presentationCountForPageViewController` get called on fine.

Any idea what I am missing? I've been going line by line with examples I've found on the web but can't find anything.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   UIPageViewController *pageController = self.pageController;
   pageController.dataSource = self;

   UIChildViewController *initialViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
   NSArray *viewControllers = @[initialViewController];
   [pageController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:nil];

   [self addChildViewController:pageController];
   [self.view addSubview:pageController.view];
   [pageController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
  }

- (UIPageViewController *)pageController
{
   return !_pageController ? _pageController =
      ({
          UIPageViewController *value = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll
                                                                  navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal
                                                                                options:nil];
          value.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
          value;
   }) : _pageController;
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pa geViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIChildViewController *)viewController
{
   NSUInteger index = viewController.index;
   return (index == 0 ) ? nil : [self viewControllerAtIndex:--index];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIChildViewController *)viewController
{
   NSUInteger index = viewController.index;
   index++;
   return (index == self.myDataSourceArray.count) ? nil : [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (UIChildViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
   UIChildViewController *childViewController = [UIChildViewController new];
   childViewController.view.frame = self.pageController.view.bounds;
   childViewController.index = index;

   ...

   return childViewController;
}

- (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:   (UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
   // The number of items reflected in the page indicator.
   return self.myDataSourceArray.count;
}

- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UI PageViewController *)pageViewController
{
   // The selected item reflected in the page indicator.
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Another direction to investigate is the view's layout. Based on your explanation and a read through of the source, it seems like the data source is correct, but perhaps its not receiving gestures at all. You could try using the view hierarchy debugging tool in Xcode (Debug > View Debugging > Capture View Hierarchy) to make sure the frame of the page view controller's view is what you expect and nothing is overlapping it.

Comment: Additionally you could add a breakpoint in `-viewDidAppear:` and inspect that the page view controller is correctly initialized and that it's data source is assigned as you expect.

Comment: thanks for the tip anthony. It wasn't that they weren't receiving gestures (the page would scroll a bit then bounce back), but this led me down the path to the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that in including my UIViewController subclass which encapsulated the UIPageViewController, I forgot in the parent view controller's `viewDidLoad` to include `addChildViewController` and `didMoveToParentViewController`

```
[self addChildViewController:myViewController];
[self.view addSubview:myViewController.view];
[myViewControllerController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Fixed the problem.